# Add data JavaScript using laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to add form data to a dB using javascript.  The postData is being read I can see in an 'Alert' but the URL isn't executing.  I've put it in as 'donorlist' and '/donorlist'.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#add-donor-form').submit(function(evt) {
  /* Act on the event */
  evt.preventDefault();

  var postData = $(this).serialize();


  $.post('/donorlist', postData, function(donor_data) {
    /*optional stuff to do after success */
    // $("#show-donor").html(donor_data);
  });

});
```

});

The form tag is:

```
  {!! Form::open(['method'=>"post", 'class' =>'form-horizontal', 'id' =>"add-donor-form"]) !!}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/donorlist','AjaxController@addonor');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understood your query correctly. You have to wrap quotes around your URI in the post statement:

```
$.post('/donorlist', postData, function(donor_data) {
    /*optional stuff to do after success */
});
```

[See Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johlton/nvnb21kp/)

Comment: What does "php artisan route:list" say?

Comment: Route::post('/donorlist','AjaxController@addonor');

Comment: POST      | donorlist                                  |                                  | App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController@addonor

Comment: If you change the route to GET, can you access it in the browser?

Comment: no, still nothing.  I still can get an alert with the postData

Comment: Could you please update your question with the respective route file snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not haveing the csrf token in js.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#add-donor-form').submit(function(evt) {
  /* Act on the event */
  evt.preventDefault();

  var postData = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr('action');

  $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

  $.post(url, postData, function(donor_data) {
    /*optional stuff to do after success */
    $("#show-donor").html(donor_data);
  });

});
```

});